# Splitting a binomial heap into 3n/8 and 5n/8 binomial heap whereas 8 divides n with O(log(n)) time

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, heaps

I ran into this exercise that says:

> With a given binomial heap with n elements and n is divisible by 8, split the heap into 2 binomial heaps, one with 3n/8 elements and the other with 5n/8 elements.

I tried using another heap as a helping heap that saves the heaps I need to merge, but I didn't exactly know how to split. Then I tried to use a stack and a queue, and I didn't get anywhere either. Can someone please help with this?

Answer (score 3):

If $n$ is even, you can split the heap into two heaps of size $\dfrac{n}2$:

For each binomial tree in the heap, remove its first child; reconstruct a heap with all the children you removed.

Since a binomial heap has at most $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$ binomial trees, this operation is done in $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$.

Using the same idea several times, you can split the heap into:

- two heaps of size $\dfrac{n}8$
- one heap of size $\dfrac{n}4$
- one heap of size $\dfrac{n}2$

Now just merge (in $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$) two pairs of those and you get the result.